# Add 3 new columns to DataFrame

Tags: python

Using Python I have the following:

```
indicators = service.getIndicators(data["temperature"])
```

The variables `data` and `indicators` are of type DataFrame.

In `indicators` I get 3 columns each with the values of one indicator.

I am adding the 3 columns to `data` `DataFrame` where first column has `Temperature` values:

```
data["InA"] = indicators[indicators.columns[0]]
data["InAB"] = indicators[indicators.columns[1]]
data["OutC"] = indicators[indicators.columns[2]]
```

Is there a shorter way to call `getIndicators` and place the result in `data` `DataFrame`.

I feel I am using to much code just for this.

Comment: `data[["InA", "InAB", "OutC"]] = indicators`?

Comment: or ```data[["InA", "InAB", "OutC"]] = indicators[0:3]``` if ```indicators``` has more columns